# Finding top performers per day in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table with four columns, the first is date, the second is Ticker, the third is perf.1 and the fourth is perf. 2.
I have filtered the table into a spilled range to only include rows that have a perf. 1 that is between two  cell values.
What I need to do is to rank or count these into a new spilled range or table so that I have only the top X number of entries per day.
The spilled range starts at W10 and I have tried

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(W10#,,1),INDEX(W10#,1,1),INDEX(W10#,,3),INDEX(W10#,1,3))-1
```

I have gotten this method to work on a table range but it includes the unfiltered data that I am trying to exclude. I am hoping to be able to average the performance of a chosen number of top daily performers and make comparisons, like top 5, 3, etc.
I should also mention their are 300 dates and 3000 rows, so an average of 10 rows per day.

Any help would be appreciated. I am not an experienced excel person or even computer person so if I have made a mistake please be tollerant.

Comment: Maybe a pivot table? Not sure of your goal but maybe a screener?

Comment: You may want to add some samples to show; anyway the way I understood it, these may be roughly the steps: use FILTER by chosen date(s). LARGE to determine the cut-off value of perf (top x) of the filtered array. FILTER again your array by (>=) the cut-off value and AVERAGE the latest filtered array.

Comment: Does it have to be immediately updating or are you okay with a solution where you have to click the "Data" ribbon's "Refresh All" button to update it?